# Can anyone help me find this soft string orchestra piece?

Tags: classical-music, string-quartet

There's this soft string piece which plays from 6:21 til 6:41 of the video. Can anyone tell me what song this is? I find it really soothing and I hope to be able to hear the whole piece.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece is "The Lark Ascending" by Ralph Vaughan William (1872-1958). It was inspired by a poem of the same name by George Meredith and originally composed for violin and piano in 1914. The better known version for violin and orchestra was completed in 1920.

Here's the piece played by Hilary Hahn: